# How to highlight a JavaScript error "Unresolved variable or type" in PyCharm using red color?

Tags: pycharm

I am currently writing JavaScript code in PyCharm, and I have noticed that PyCharm highlights JavaScript errors with a grey color, specifically indicating "Unresolved variable or type." How I can configure PyCharm to highlight these errors using a red color instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Editor | Color Scheme | General.

Under Errors and Warnings, you find the Error option. There you can change the color.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Thx. However, it requires changing the effects for Weak Warnings. PyChars considers a reference to an unknown variable to be a weak warning, not an error, which is a bit weird.

Comment: That's indeed strange. I tested it and for me, in my PyCharm (version 2022.2.3) it is an error and not a weak warning.